# Monitoring a website that contains a defined string with Zabbix

Tags: string, monitor, zabbix

How can I monitor a website with Zabbix 2.2 that contains a defined string in the title?
For example: https://stackoverflow.com/ contains 'Stack Overflow' in the .

Now I want to get an email, if there is another string instead of 'Stack Overflow' in the title. How can I do this?

Is it the required string in the steps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are two main options:

1. use [Web monitoring](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/web_monitoring) and put your string into "Required string" field;
2. use [web.page.regexp[] item](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent) and put your string into the <regexp> parameter.

In both cases, you can make a trigger that will alert you if the string is not there.